# What could be the cause of these http-livestream artefacts in google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, ffmpeg, html5-video, h.264, http-live-streaming

Here is the http-livestream setup: The server is running ffmpeg with the DASH protocol and h264 encoding. The client is using Dash.js. Resolution is fixed to 1920x1080, with 24 bit depth, and 60hz.

The artefacting (image below) is only present when the last row of the video is within chrome viewport (so it disapears if the page is scrolled up). It manifests itself as stretching of the center row of pixels downwards, and appears to only affect some color channels.

I have attempted changing the bitrate, and cutting the last row from the source, thinking the issue could be on the server side, without any impact. The fact that the issue depends on the position in the viewport makes me suspect a glitch in chrome itself.

I have also attempted to force hardware decoding off in chrome:\flags and it does not solve the issue.

Please submit your hypothesis on what could be the cause of this issue. Thanks.

[image: screenshot]

---

### Update #1

Here is the ffmpeg command line and logs:

```
export DISPLAY=:0 && ffmpeg -f x11grab -framerate 60 -video_size 1920x1080 -i :0.0+0,0 -draw_mouse 0 -f dash -utc_timing_url https://time.akamai.com/?iso -streaming 1 -seg_duration 2 -frag_duration 0.033 -fflags nobuffer -fflags flush_packets -c:v h264 -preset ultrafast data/stream.mpd
```

And the logs:

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[x11grab @ 0x561ca34b9980] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, x11grab, from ':0.0+0,0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1618941693.853256, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[0] / 0x524742), bgr0, 1920x1080, 60 fps, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x561ca34c5300] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2 AVX512
[libx264 @ 0x561ca34c5300] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 4.2, 4:4:4 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x561ca34c5300] 264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=6 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
[dash @ 0x561ca34c3740] No bit rate set for stream 0
[dash @ 0x561ca34c3740] Opening 'data/init-stream0.m4s' for writing
Output #0, dash, to 'data/stream.mpd':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264), yuv444p, 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 60 fps, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
[dash @ 0x561ca34c3740] Opening 'data/chunk-stream0-00001.m4s.tmp' for writing
frame=   34 fps=0.0 q=15.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.43 bitrate=N/A dup=5 drop=0 speed=0.836x    
frame=   65 fps= 64 q=15.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.95 bitrate=N/A dup=5 drop=0 speed=0.929x    
frame=   96 fps= 62 q=15.0 size=N/A time=00:00:01.46 bitrate=N/A dup=5 drop=2 speed=0.955x    
frame=  126 fps= 62 q=15.0 size=N/A time=00:00:01.96 bitrate=N/A dup=5 drop=3 speed=0.962x    
frame=  157 fps= 62 q=15.0 size=N/A time=00:00:02.48 bitrate=N/A dup=5 drop=3 speed=0.973x    
frame=  188 fps= 61 q=15.0 size=N/A time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=N/A dup=5 drop=3 speed=0.98x    
frame=  217 fps= 61 q=15.0 size=N/A time=00:00:03.48 bitrate=N/A dup=5 drop=3 speed=0.977x    
frame=  247 fps= 61 q=15.0 size=N/A time=00:00:03.98 bitrate=N/A dup=6 drop=3 speed=0.976x    
[dash @ 0x561ca34c3740] Opening 'data/stream.mpd.tmp' for writing
[dash @ 0x561ca34c3740] Opening 'data/chunk-stream0-00002.m4s.tmp' for writing
frame=  279 fps= 61 q=15.0 size=N/A t
```

Comment: Very broad question. Show your ffmpeg command and the complete log.

Comment: FFMpeg and client show no error message. Also, while the question is broad, i stated that I was looking for hypothesis to explore, more than a sample solution. Someone else must have seen similar artifacts.

Comment: The ffmpeg command and output will still be informative even if you do not see any error messages. Right not I can't even come up with a hypothesis without more info.

Comment: Fair enough, I have added the command line and logs in an update of the original post.

Comment: Try adding the `-vf format=yuv420p` output option.

Comment: Very interesting, the issue seems to be gone with this colorspace instead of rgb24. No I am very curious as why a colorspace issue could be intermittent, as described above. Does chrome have specific issues with rgb24? Please enter your explanation or at least hypothesis and I will select your awnser for the bounty.

I will test YUV444 and other spaces to see if they also work and note the results.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `-vf format=yuv420p` output option for YUV 4:2:0 [chroma subsampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling). This is the only widely supported chroma subsampling scheme for H.264.

Your input pixel format is bgr0. Your output is yuv444p. ffmpeg tries to preserve as much fidelity as it can so it auto converts it to a pixel format supported by the selected encoder that most resembles the source. In this case it is yuv444p (YUV 4:4:4) which is not universally supported.